# Xamarin.Uitest app.Tap() has a different behavior between 2 different phones (Android)

Tags: automation, xamarin.android, automated-tests, ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

I have an issue.

With the same code, `app.Tap(myquery)` work on LG 6.0.1, and it does not work on HTC 6.0.
(The issue happend with pop-ups)

I made an `app.Flash(myquery)` to make sure that my button can be found, and the `app.Flash(myquery)` is working fine for both phones.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with your note "The issue happened with pop-ups"? More details on your observations between the device that fails vs. works could be helpful in narrowing down the cause.

Comment: For some smartphones, when I made the Tap it work, and the button from that popup is clicked, 
and when It fail, the Tap does not work and the click event does not pass, even if the query is correct and it is finding the button that I need to click on it

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add a WaitForElement statement? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/timeouts/

This could help if the issue is a race condition, because if the popup is much faster or slower on one device compared to the other, that could affect how consistently the test works.

Comment: Yes I am doing that already. 
P.S : The query on console is showing that it found 1 result (the expected result)

Comment: Since the query on the console is reporting the result it sounds like it may be a bug. If you have a Test Cloud account you can log into testcloud.xamarin.com and click on the support link; please note that to investigate the bug they may need a sample to reproduce the issue including UITest source code and an APK to run it against.